# Error en los argumentos Python

Tags: python, backend

Trato de hacer un CRUD con python con la API FastApi y las librerias de SQLAlchemy y Pidantic.

Me da error al pasarle los parámetros, os dejo aquí el código que trato de ejecutar desde el swagger de FastApi para crear un personaje:

Esta es el modelo tabla:

```
Tablapersonajes = Table("personajes", meta, Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column("personaje", String(255)),
Column("casa_hogwarts", String(255)),
Column("descripcion", String(1000)),
Column("progenitor", Integer, ForeignKey("personajes.id")),
Column("fecha_nacimiento", String(255)),
Column("imagen", String(255)))
```

Este es el schema para retornar datos y manipularlos, hecha con Pydantic:

```
class PersonajesBase (BaseModel):
    id: Optional [int]
    personaje: str
    casa_hogwarts: str
    descripcion: str
    progenitor: Optional [int]
    fecha_nacimiento: str
    imagen: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Aqui está la función crear personaje:

```
def create_personajes(db: Session, personajes: PersonajesBase):
    db_personaje = Tablapersonajes(personaje=personajes.personaje,
                                   casa_hogwarts=personajes.casa_hogwarts,
                                   fecha_nacimiento=personajes.fecha_nacimiento,
                                   progenitor=personajes.progenitor,
                                   descripcion=personajes.descripcion,
                                   imagen=personajes.imagen)
    db.add(db_personaje)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_personaje)
    return db_personaje
```

Y aqui cuando lo creo en el metodo post de la api:

```
@personaje.post("/personajes", response_model=PersonajesBase)
def create_personajes(personaje: PersonajesBase, db: Session):
    db_personaje = get_personaje(db, id=personaje.id)
    if db_personaje:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Personaje ya registrado")
    return create_personajes(db=db, personaje=personaje)
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'> is a valid pydantic field
 type
```

No se si es porque no he hecho las tablas de otra forma, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: el error es porque no estas retornando un json. Puedes ver [esto](https://fixexception.com/fastapi/invalid-args-for-response-field-hint-check-that-type-is-a-valid-pydantic-field-type/)